# Shortcode to find and replace URL

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I'm trying to create a shortcode that will search within some specified text for a link and replace it with one that I specify. For example:

```
[scode]Click on <a href="www.X.com">this link</a>[scode]
[scode]Click on <a href="www.Y.com">this link</a>[scode]
```

...will both be changed to:

```
[scode]Click on <a href="www.Z.com">this link</a>[scode]
```

I'm trying to put together a function that will search for links and replace them with the one that I specify. Here's what I have right now:

```
// Adds [hide] shortcode for hiding content from non-registered users.

function hide_text( $atts,$content) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in () ) {
        return $content;
    }
    else {
        $pattern = '(?<=href=("|\'))[^"\']+(?=("|\'))';
        $newurl = "http://replacementurl.com";
        $content = preg_replace($pattern,$newurl,$content);
        echo $content;
          }
    }
add_shortcode( 'hide', 'hide_text' );
```

This just crashes the site, though. I'm not a PHP expert (much less an expert on regex), but are there at least any glaring irregularities in my code?

Or perhaps there's just a better way to go about this and I'm making it way more complicated than it needs to be?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested, I turned on debug log, which showed me that I had an extra `}` in the code. Updated code is shown above. Now the site isn't crashing, but the link and text within the shortcode is completely erased, just blank.

Comment: [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see errors. the one thing that stands out immediately is the quotes in your pattern.

Comment: There should also be a `;` at the end of the `$newurl` line.

Comment: Yep, had the `;` in there, sorry.

Comment: @Milo debug log showed that there was an extra `}` in there. I removed it, but now the link (and the text) is missing entirely, just a blank space. Will update answer.

Comment: you shouldn"t use a shortcode for that. Use a filter in your functions.php, that filters out the related content. see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Comment: Also, your function should `return`, not `echo`... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

Comment: @pixeline but wouldn't that just replace all URLs? The reason for using a shortcode is because it needs to be targeted. How is that possible with making a filter?

Comment: are there any other way to recognize those urls? Like a `class="hideme"` attribute/value pair?

Comment: @pixeline Well the idea is to make it user friendly. If it were just me running the site, that'd be one thing. But the site will be operated by people unfamiliar with code, hence the use of shortcodes to make it easier for them. So I don't want to make them have to enter raw html (e.g. like putting them in classes).

Answer (score 2):

Your shortcode function should look like this:

```
function replace_url_for_nonlogged( $atts, $content = "") {
  if ( is_user_logged_in () ) return $content;
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'replace' => 'http://www.default_replace_url.com',
  ), $atts ) );
  $pattern = '/href=("|\')((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)("|\')/';
  return preg_replace($pattern, "href=\"$replace\"", $content);
}
add_shortcode( 'scode', 'replace_url_for_nonlogged' );
```

Then you can use the shortcode like this:

```
[scode]Lorem <a href="http://reservedurl.com">ipsum</a> dolor <a href='http://resersinglequoted.com'>simet</a>.[/scode]
```

and the output became:

```
Lorem <a href="http://www.default_replace_url.com">ipsum</a> dolor <a href="http://www.default_replace_url.com">simet</a>.
```

the url replaced is setted as default in the `replace_url_for_nonlogged` function.

If you want you can pass the replacent url via shortcode att, e.g.

```
[scode replace="http://www.google.com"]Lorem <a href="http://reservedurl.com">ipsum</a> dolor <a href='http://resersinglequoted.com'>simet</a>.[/scode]
```

and this time the output became:

```
Lorem <a href="http://www.google.com">ipsum</a> dolor <a href="http://www.google.com">simet</a>.
```

---

[image]

Comment: Did you test this? It's not changing the link for me...

Comment: @TimMcClure are you sure that when you test you are **not** logged in? I've tested, and it works for me. See the added screenshot on answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function timMcLure_hide_text( $atts,$content="") {
    if (!is_user_logged_in () ) {
      $pattern = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
      $newurl = "http://replacementurl.com";
      $content = preg_replace($pattern, $newurl, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'urlhide', 'timMcLure_hide_text' );
```

Then use `[urlhide]`as a shortcode.

Please try and report as i cannot easily test this.

Comment: This deletes all content within the shortcode. Aren't you making `$content` empty in the first line?

Comment: no, i'm telling the function that $content's default value is empty.